# Problem in setting up eclim on ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, eclim

I downloaded eclim, and according to the installation guide 
it requires Eclipse Helios 3.6.x.

So, I went and installed that version of Eclispe manually because it is not at Ubuntu's repositories.

What happened next was that, when I tried installing eclim, it said that it cannot recognize the eclipse version that I have.

Do you have any suggestions of how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Eclipse that you install manually is not usually on the path that Eclipse is installed to when using the software center. I had this problem too while trying to install eclim.

There are two ways to fix it.

1. You can specify where the new Eclipse is installed to from your manual installation. For example, I manually installed Helios to $HOME/eclipse. When the installer gets to the point where it asks for eclipse's path, I specified it as /home/username/eclipse, replacing username with my name of course. That should find the helios installation, and not the installation in /usr/lib/eclipse.
2. The second way to do it is to manually make and install eclim from the repositories. The guide for this is here, http://eclim.org/guides/development.html#development-build. That will work you through building eclim from the development build, which may be better anyway as there may be new features not in the release version. Be sure to specify the eclipse home files in the Ant command, like so, `ant -Declipse.home=/where/you/installed/eclipseto`

Hope this helped, and merry days using eclim. It's really great.

Comment: If my answer really did solver your problem, it's good Stack overflow practice to accept my answer by pressing the check next to it.